# Minecraft FPS at Windows and Linux

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux, windows-10, virtualization

At my pc (intel core i3-10100, GTX1660 SUPER 6GB) Minecraft runs at max graphics with 100+ fps. But At Linux(Mint)(in virtual box), it runs at ~20-30 fps, why so slow?

P.S. Minecraft versions is 16.0+

Comment: this is more a question about virtualbox than a game, but virtualbox runs very slowly due to the fact that ist virtualizing everything

Comment: Topcode, bruh, is this question acceptable for this site, it is will not be deleted?

Comment: You could just use the native version of Minecraft

Comment: Addy, I'm just interested in virtual box performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**VirtualBox can’t efficiently run “heavy” applications like Minecraft**, as it is emulating an entire computer, which takes a lot of processing power for that process alone. Additionally, VirtualBox can only use around a third of the host computer’s power, in order that it won’t cause the host to crash. But don’t be alarmed, as *VirtualBox will always run worse than a real machine, no matter how much processing power is allocated.*

Comment: Good, exhaustive answer, thanks!

Comment: @reORION You’re welcome. Glad I can help.